# How to make in-apps for multi-account iOS/Mac app?

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store, mac-app-store

Having an app with login to our server. We want to introduce nonconsumable in-apps, but I don't know how to make an in-app available to one server account and unavailable to another server account on a single device. What product id's should I use? Are there any dynamics available in itunes connect? Maybe I should use a consumable in-app to "buy" virtual goods? If so, how can i validate this on my server (I know i can do it for non consumables, but it looks like [it won't work for consumables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366214/verify-consumable-in-app-purchase-for-mac-os-x-on-server-side))
Also, if I implement the subject above, how can I correctly restore my purchases on another itunes account but the same server login?
What are the best practicies for this?